# NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED in Firefox when uploading file from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to allow users to upload files without causing the page to change when they upload the files. To do this, I'm using an iframe, which I'm adding a form and a file input to, then submitting the form within the (hidden) iframe. This works just fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox.

Below is code which causes this problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #pretty-button { background: blue; }
            #hidden-uploader { display: none; }
        </style>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var btn = document.getElementById('pretty-button');
            var filename_output = document.getElementById('filename');
            var upload_iframe = document.getElementById('hidden-uploader');

            btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.body.appendChild(upload_iframe);
                _document = upload_iframe.contentDocument;

                var form = _document.createElement('form');
                form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
                form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
                form.setAttribute('action', '.');

                var file_input = _document.createElement('input');
                file_input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                file_input.setAttribute('name', 'document');

                form.appendChild(file_input);
                _document.body.appendChild(form);
                file_input.click();

                file_input.addEventListener('change', function() {
                    console.log('file selected');
                    form.submit();
                    upload_iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
                        console.log('file uploaded');
                    });
                });

            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="pretty-button">Choose a File</button>
        <span id="filename"></span>
        <iframe id="hidden-uploader"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

On firefox, this fails with `NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED:` on line 33, which is `form.submit()`, when a file is selected.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured the problem, which is in the line

```
document.body.appendChild(upload_iframe);
```

This causes the iframe to reload itself, which means that the contentDocument of the iframe before it is re-appended to the document body is different from the contentDocument of the iframe after it is re-appended to the document body. The reloading occurs while the file dialog is open.

This can be verified by making the following changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #pretty-button { background: blue; }
            #hidden-uploader { display: none; }
        </style>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var btn = document.getElementById('pretty-button');
            var filename_output = document.getElementById('filename');
            var upload_iframe = document.getElementById('hidden-uploader');

            btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.body.appendChild(upload_iframe);
                _document = upload_iframe.contentDocument;

                var form = _document.createElement('form');
                form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
                form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
                form.setAttribute('action', '.');

                var file_input = _document.createElement('input');
                file_input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                file_input.setAttribute('name', 'document');

                form.appendChild(file_input);
                _document.body.appendChild(form);
                file_input.click();
                // So far, the iframe hasn't reloaded.

                file_input.addEventListener('change', function() {
                    /* Because the iframe loads in less time than it 
                     * takes for the user to select a file, the iframe
                     * has now reloaded, and _document refers to the 
                     * contentDocument of an iframe which is no longer
                     * attached to the page.
                     */
                    console.log('file selected');
                    var _newDocument = upload_iframe.contentDocument;
                    console.log(_document === _newDocument); // false in Firefox, true in Chrome
                    form.submit();
                    upload_iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
                        console.log('file uploaded');
                    });
                });

            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="pretty-button">Choose a File</button>
        <span id="filename"></span>
        <iframe id="hidden-uploader"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

By removing the offending line, the above starts working in Firefox.